# Add Int values of RDD[String,Array[String,Int]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD[String,Array[String,Int]],

```
    ["abc",[("asd",1),("asd",3),("cvd",2),("cvd",2),("xyz",1)]]
```

I want to turn it into-

```
     ["abc",[("asd",4),("cvd",4),("xyz",1)]]
```

I tried-

```
     val y=hashedRdd.map(f=> (f._1,f._2.map(_._2).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)))
```

But this returns RDD[String,Int]
I want the return in RDD[String,Array[String,Int]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the `Array` and calculate the `sum` of values.

```
// Raw rdd
val hashedRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("abc",Array(("asd",1),("asd",3),("cvd",2),("cvd",2),("xyz",1)))
))

//Group by first value and calculate the sum
val y = hashedRdd.map(x => {
  (x._1, x._2.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum))
})
```

Output:

```
y.foreach(println)
(abc,Map(xyz -> 1, asd -> 4, cvd -> 4))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to `reduce` on the tuples after `groupBy`(of the first entry):

```
@ hashedRdd.map { f => (f._1, f._2.groupBy{ _._1 }.map{ _._2.reduce{ (a,b)=>(a._1, a._2+b._2) } } )}.collect
res11: Array[(String, Map[String, Int])] = Array(("abc", Map("xyz" -> 1, "asd" -> 4, "cvd" -> 4)))
```

Comment: What are you trying to say by a._1?? (a,b) is the tuple(String,Int)? then a does not have ._1 and this expression is not working..

Comment: @Rasika did you remove the `.map(_._2)` ?

Comment: Yes, I used the same expression as you mentioned. Did not work.

Comment: @Rasika here's an update, I've tested this with your rdd. I had missed that your original wasn't grouping.